# How to combine multiple import statements into one in React / Nextjs app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

To handle SSR, instead of

```
import EditorJS from '@editorjs'
```

I am doing

```
const EditorJS = dynamic(
  () => import('react-editor-js'),
  { ssr: false }
)
```

I have to do the same for

```
import Header from '@editorjs/header';
import Embed from '@editorjs/embed'
import Table from '@editorjs/table'
import Paragraph from '@editorjs/paragraph'
```

Is there anyway to combine all the imports into one dynamic import instead of doing more of this for every import?

```
const Header = dynamic(
  () => import('@editorjs/header'),
  { ssr: false }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with the names of all your libraries and import them with dynamic const names:

```
imports = ['@editorjs/header', '@editorjs/embed', '@editorjs/table', '@editorjs/paragraph']; 

imports.forEach((value)=>{
    let name = value.slice(value.indexOf('/')+1);
    
    eval('const '+ name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1) + ' = ' + "dynamic(() => import('" + value+ "'),{ ssr: false })" + ';');
})
```